# What is the meaning of tangent of 90 degrees

Tags: rust, trigonometry

I was trying to get my head around how invalid mathematical values are handled in Rust, so I thought I will have a look at what happens if I take the tangent of 90 degrees. What I didn't expect is that I will get a 'proper' value so when I run this [code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b3ec20a41f25ecd7428807267d5df1fe&version=stable):

```
fn main() {
    use std::f32;

    for i in 89997..90003 {
        let angle = (i as f32) / 1000.0;
        println!("tan of {}: {}", angle, angle.to_radians().tan());
    }
}
```

I get the following result:

```
tan of 89.997: 19124.42
tan of 89.998: 28665.936
tan of 89.999: 57208.06
tan of 90: -22877334
tan of 90.001: -57312.285
tan of 90.002: -28692.08
```

What is the meaning of -22877334 in this context?

Comment: `90` may be a value which can be precisely represented, but `angle.to_radians()` is pi/2, which cannot. Clearly you expect tan(pi/2) to be infinity, but actually it's calculating tan(pi/2 * x) where x is some value very close to one. Try `180.to_radians().tan()` and you'll see what I mean.